# Bash: Using process IDs in a shell script

Tags: bash, parent-child, pid

I am a bit confused on the uses of PIDs and parent/children processes. I have been reading up on them and I understand as far as the fact that when a program starts it makes an exact copy of itself (the child) and each of them have unique PIDs. But I am not sure if I can use it in a shell to tell me when certain aspects of that shell program have finished.

For a better example (pseudo code):

```
 for ((i = 0; i < 10; i++))
  for a_name in "${anArray[@]}";do
     a series of math equations that allow the values associated with a_name to run in the background simultaneously using '&' earlier in the code         
  done
wait

  for a_name in "${anArray[@]}";do
     same as above but diff equations
  done
wait
done
```

I am hoping to be able to see when any given value is finished in the command, so that that particular value can move on to the next for loop and command.

I have seen that wait can take a job identifier as an argument (wait%1 or wait $PPID) but I am not really sure how those would be implemented.

Does anyone have advice on how to use PIDs and/or have a link to a super good tutorial? (and I mean *super* good, I need some laymen's terms thrown in there)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to just run tasks in the background?

Comment: I am confused by your need here.  unless you explicitly tell the loop not to wait for completion, it will wait for each command to complete before moving on...  Essentially what you appear to be looking for

Comment: I want tasks to run in the background. And I know that you can use &  for that. But how do you know when each background task completes? Also, when it completes how can you make it so that it will not wait for the rest of the background tasks to finish?

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: What's the value of backgrounding your process at all? What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: I suppose what I am trying to ask is this. Will the first value from the array move onto the next loop without waiting for the rest of the values in the array? And if it does wait then is there a way to use PID to get around that wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait on a single process:

```
command ${array[0]} &
waiton=$!
# Do some more stuff which might finish before process $waiton
wait $waiton
```

You can wait on all children processes:

```
someLongRunningCommand &
(
    for value in "${array[@]}"; do
        command "$value" &
    done
    wait
)
# wait with no arguments waits on all children processes of the current
# process. That doesn't include `someLongRunningCommand`, as it is not
# a child of the process running the subshell.
```

Other situations are trickier and may be better handled by `xargs`, `parallel`, or some other method.